# Formik Resetting the Initial Values using Yup validation with it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik, yup

I have a piece of code where Formik is used in the #React app with #Typescript and Yup validation. The problem I am facing is that on setting the values in a Select element it does not change the value at all or perhaps it immediately resets the value to the initial value as given in the Formik initial value object. What should I do about it? (No code is available here. But hopefully)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.

### In my case ***enableReinitialize*** is the culprit.

It was just the ***enableReinitialize*** property in the initial Values object set to true. You just need to remove this and you are good to go. I tried dozens of patches to cope with the problem and due to this property, each and every property was not working according to the logic. I also used #MUI #DatePicker #MUIDatePicker which was having issues because of this one property.
Hope it helps many others.

### *#Coding*